# jQuery select list validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validation script to validate three select lists on a form.

The issue I am having is it is only working on the first `select` list. This is the jQuery code I am using for the first select list with a name and id of Department, the first `option` has a value of 0:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#form1').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        Department: {
            selectcheck: true
        }
    }
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectcheck', function (value) {
    return (value != '0');
}, "required");
});
```

The second `select` list with a name and id of FBType, again the first `option` has a value of 0, this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#form1').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        FBType: {
            selectcheck: true
        }
    }
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectcheck', function (value) {
    return (value != '0');
}, "required");
});
```

Can any one see why the second select list will not work. I am getting no errors the form just submits.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$('#form1').validate({...` is supposed to be used to initialize the plugin on *your entire form at once*.  You would not call `.validate()` for each input, nor can you.  The plugin only uses the first instance and will ignore all others.

You also would not need to call `.addMethod()` more than once.  Once you call `jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectcheck',...`, the `selectcheck` method has been created and can be used multiple times.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectcheck', function(value) { // create new rule
        return (value != '0');
    }, "required");

    $('#form1').validate({ // initialize the plugin on "#form1"
        rules: {
            Department: {
                selectcheck: true
            },
            FBType: {
                selectcheck: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/03rrL727/**

---

**Note**:  with the proper HTML markup, you would not need to write a custom method to make a `<select>` required.  The first `<option>` simply needs a `value=''` attribute; then use the `required` rule.

```
<select name="Department">
    <option value=''>please select...</option>
    <option value='1'>option 1</option>
    <option value='2'>option 2</option>
</select>
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/03rrL727/1/**